# A function to copy an array and store it in another array

Tags: arrays, c, function

Trying to create a void function to return the copy of the a[n] array into b[n] array. I am also trying to reverse the order of the array. Every time I return it I get a bunch of random output numbers instead of the numbers in the array. I am not quite sure where it is getting the random numbers from, any help would be great. I have looked at other similar questions on here but can not seem to get it to work for me. The name of the functions of have to stay the same.

```
 void copy(int n, int a[n], int b[n]){                                          
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){                                            
   b[i] = a[i];                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                               
 }

void reverse(int n, int a[n]){                                                                                           
 int rev = n - 1;                                                                                                       
 int stop = n -1;                                                                                                       
 for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++){                                                                                       
  rev = a[i];                                                                                                          
  a[i] = a[stop];                                                                                                      
  a[stop] = rev;                                                                                                       
  stop--;                                                                                                              
 }                                                                                                                      
}          


int main() {
int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int b[N];
printf("This is an array: ");
print(N, a);
copy(N, b, a);
printf("This is a copy of the array: ");
print(N, b);
printf("This array is the reverse of the original array: ");
reverse(N, b);
print(N, b);
printf("\n");
}
```

I am still getting this as the output.

This is an array:   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

This is a copy of the array: 91455776032616  0  0-47662827221932-4766295202193254227025632766

This array is the reverse of the original array: 91455776032616  0  0-47662827221932-4766295202193254227025632766

Comment: Arrays in general are not terminated by `'\0'`. Only strings are. You are passing the length along, why don't you use it? Also you want `b[i] = a[i];` instead of `b[n] = a[n];`

Comment: And fyi,  `copy(N, b, a);` in `main` is targeting `a` as the copy destination, using `b` as the source of the copy. Since `b` is not initialized... yeah. Even after fixing the loops this is still wrong.

Comment: The loop condition should be `i < n`

Comment: also just as a remark, `void` functions, i.e. functions with return type `void` don't "return"' a value, so your expression "Trying to create a void function to return the copy of the..."  is incorrect. When you use the word "return" it means that your function will have a return value, and thus the return type can't be `void`.

Comment: I forgot to mention the name of the functions need to stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

You had several errors:

1. You should use `b[i] = a[i];` instead of `b[n] = a[n];`
2. Don't use `b[n]='\0'`
3. Arrays don't end at `'\0'`. You should use the condition `i < n` to check ending of array in for loop.
4. Pass the arrays in functions like `int a[]` and not `int a[n]`.
5. Pass the arrays in the function in correct order i.e `copy(N, a, b);`

```
void copy(int n, int a[], int b[]){
  for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
   b[i] = a[i];
  }
  //b[n] = '\0';
 }

void reverse(int n, int a[]){
 int rev = n - 1;
 int stop = n -1;
 for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++){
  rev = a[i];
  a[i] = a[stop];
  a[stop] = rev;
  stop--;
 }
}
void print(int n, int a[]){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int N = 10;
int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int b[N];
printf("This is an array: ");
print(N, a);
copy(N, a, b);
printf("This is a copy of the array: ");
print(N, b);
printf("This array is the reverse of the original array: ");
reverse(N, b);
print(N, b);
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: No `cout` please. This is C!

Comment: In `reverse`, `rev` doesn't need an initializer. More idiomatic: `for (i = 0; i < stop; ++i, --stop)`

Comment: @CraigEstey I know. I didn't want to change the logic of his code. I wanted to keep the code as close to the original one so that he doesn't get overwhelmed. I just listed and removed the errors.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. For novice OPs, what I do is produce a few [usually 3] versions. The first just fixes the immediate errors. If the code can be simplified/improved, I add those [in a progression]. That way, OP gets the fix and some ideas on better coding. [They seem to like that approach]. If OP's code is way off the mark, I usually do a complete refactoring (i.e. it gets OP on the right track sooner/faster). From "The Elements of Programming Style" by Kernighan/Plauger: _Don't patch bad code -- rewrite it_ For experienced OPs, I just do the fix with cleanup in a single block

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for the tip! I will follow the same form now on.

Answer (score 0):

This check `a[i] != '\0'` could make a sense for copying strings. But this is not your case.

Also this assignment

```
b[n] = a[n];
```

can invoke undefined behavior if passed arrays have `n` elements.

Declare and define the function `copy` the following way

```
void copy( const int a1[], int a2[], size_t n )
{                                          
    for ( size_t i = 0; i != n; i++ )
    {                                            
       a2[i] = a1[i];                                                                
    }                                                                             
}
```

and call the function like

```
copy( a, b, N );
```

Within the function reverse this statement

```
int rev = n - 1;
```

does not make a sense.

Declare and define the function like

```
void reverse( int a[], size_t n )
{                                                                                           
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {                                                                                       
        int tmp = a[i];                                                                                                          
        a[i] = a[n - i - 1];                                                                                                      
        a[n - i - 1] = tmp;                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                      
}
```

and call the function like

```
reverse( b, N );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   10

void copy( const int a1[], int a2[], size_t n )
{                                          
    for ( size_t i = 0; i != n; i++ )
    {                                            
       a2[i] = a1[i];                                                                
    }                                                                             
}

void reverse( int a[], size_t n )
{                                                                                           
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {                                                                                       
        int tmp = a[i];                                                                                                          
        a[i] = a[n - i - 1];                                                                                                      
        a[n - i - 1] = tmp;                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                      
} 

FILE * print( const int a[], size_t n, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i != N ; i++ )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int b[N];

    printf( "This is an array: " );

    putc( '\n', print( a, N, stdout ) );
    
    copy( a, b, N );

    printf( "This is a copy of the array: " );
    putc( '\n', print( b, N, stdout ) );

    printf("This array is the reverse of the original array: " );
    reverse( b, N );
    putc( '\n', print( b, N, stdout ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
This is an array: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
This is a copy of the array: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
This array is the reverse of the original array: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: I see you changed the parameter order  to `void copy( const int a1[], int a2[], size_t n )`.   With [C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features), OP's original order `void copy( size_t n, const int a1[], int a2[] )` remains useful.

Comment: I do not know much about C. What is 'size_t'? Could I just use 'int'?

Comment: @bildungsroman11 It is an unsigned integer type. sizes of arrays are calculated by values of the type size_t. For example teh operator sizeof returns a value of the type size_t. But in your case you may use the type int instead of size_t.

Comment: I understand thank you for clearing that up. Unfortunately I have to keep the name of the functions like the original code I posted.

Comment: @bildungsroman11 You may change the order of parameters,